# Linux vnc port closed

Tags: linux, centos, vnc-server

I have a vps server on Centos and I have installed a vnc server by this tutorial:

[how-to-install-vnc-server-on-centos-6](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-centos-6/)

Well the server is running but I can't connect to it, I have scanned by nmap and I cannot find the `port 5901`. I tried to disable iptables but I got nothing!

I have already added this line in ip tables and save/restart it but it doesn't work!

> iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport
>   --dports 5901:5903,6001:6003 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

Try this iptables rules 1) is not secured connection rules 2) is secured and only connect with your given ip address
*just replace the "192.168.10.0/24" with you IP range

1)rules set

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6001 -j ACCEPT
```

2)rules set

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5901 -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6001 -j REJECT

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5901 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6001 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: then I like 2 see your configuration file

Comment: for testing purpose just use the 1) rules set